# Appium - Register many devices to selenium grid docker

Tags: selenium, docker, appium

I'm studying to use docker.
1. I connect 2 real devices to my computer.
2. I have this docker-compose file:

```
# Note: It requires docker-compose 1.13.0
#
# Usage: docker-compose up -d
version: "2.2"

services:
  # Selenium hub
  selenium_hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.14.0-curium
    ports:
      - 4444:4444

  # Using Appium Docker Android  
  real_device:
    image: appium/appium
    depends_on:
      - selenium_hub
    network_mode: "service:selenium_hub"
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb
      - ~/.android:/root/.android
      - ./appFolder:/root/tmp
    environment:
      - CONNECT_TO_GRID=true
      - SELENIUM_HOST=selenium_hub
```

3. I start docker like this, it shows there are 2 devices:
   [console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlTSl.png)
4. But when I open my browser, there is one device only:
   [Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8Egm.png)
   How can I connect 2 of my devices to grid docker?
   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to run Appium in grid you need to setup config file. Check out this documentation [here](http://appium.io/docs/en/advanced-concepts/grid/) and [here](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/appium-tutorials/connecting-appium-to-selenium-grid-example) to know how.

Comment: Thank you @Wasiq Bhamla. I know the methods in your link, but this is appium and selenium grid in docker. Selenium grid docker will generate configuration automatically.

Comment: The config file discussed in the links I shared is not generated by selenium grid. That you need to create in json format and add as server capability when starting Appium server.